# Grouping multiple object data types from merged csv files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mergesort, pandas-groupby

I am taking a data science bootcamp and currently covering merging and sorting csv files in pandas/jupyter notebook in order to create new dataframes. An issue that I keep running into is that when I try to group two non-numerical objects (e.g. "City", "City-type" - urban, suburban, rural, etc.), I either error out, or am forced to create an array. In previous exercises, arrays weren't an issue because I could work around them. In this particular instance I absolutely need to use the data contained in the array for a scatter plot. I've asked the professors how to fix this (but only got cagey responses b/c it's homework), gone through countless feeds, and reviewed all of our previous lessons, but can't seem to figure it out. So, is there a way to group two non-numerical columns in pandas without creating an array? I'm new, been hit with a ton of material all at once, and feel like I'm missing something basic. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your DataFrame? And what aggregation function do you intend to use with your `groupby` - sum, count, mean, etc.?

Comment: [Original Data upon inner merge of two CSVs][1]
[Method that I was able to use to get the array][2]
[New Data Frame][3]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GJtT.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wQ55.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/95dwU.png

Comment: I posted the images from the jupyter notebook file I'm working from. I tried both .set_index, and reset_index methods per the professor's instructions, but I'm not getting the results I need.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots in your comments above, I see that your `pyber_df.groupby("City")["Type"].unique()` call is producing a one-member list for each city, instead of just giving you the string representation of each city type.

*If you can safely assume that each city has one and only one type*, then your best bet is to replace `unique` with `first`:

```
city_type = pyber_df.groupby("City")["Type"].first()
```

Comment: Cool. I’ll give it a try. Thank you!